# PHP Upload single file based on multiple variable IDs

Tags: php, arrays, file, loops, upload

I'm trying to allow my system to upload a single file depending on several jobs selected from a list.

The system will essentially select the jobs, allow a user to upload a file related to all those jobs, which are stored in a database with a unique id.

So far it only seems to upload the file for the first id within the array. How do I upload the file multiple times, using each job ID within the file name to define each file separately?

This is the loop so far:

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["type"] != "") {

                    $count++;
                    $uploadComplete = 0;

                    $newFileName = date("YmdHis");
                    $newFileName = $newFileName . "-TEST".$multiId[$i]."-";
                    $newFileName2 = $newFileName . "-";

                    $newFileName2 = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
                    $newFileName2 = str_replace(" ", "-", $newFileName2);


                    $ext = strrchr($_FILES["file"]["name"], ".");

                    if (($ext == ".png")
                    || ($ext == ".jpeg")
                    || ($ext == ".pjpeg")
                    || ($ext == ".jpg")
                    || ($ext == ".PNG")
                    || ($ext == ".JPEG")
                    || ($ext == ".PJPEG")
                    || ($ext == ".JPG")) {
                        $fileType = "image";    
                    }

                    if (($ext == ".pdf")
                    || ($ext == ".doc")
                    || ($ext == ".docx")
                    || ($ext == ".zip")
                    || ($ext == ".PDF")
                    || ($ext == ".DOC")
                    || ($ext == ".DOCX")
                    || ($ext == ".ZIP")) {
                        $fileType = "file";
                    }



                    if (($ext == ".png")
                    || ($ext == ".jpeg")
                    || ($ext == ".pjpeg")
                    || ($ext == ".jpg")
                    || ($ext == ".pdf")
                    || ($ext == ".doc")
                    || ($ext == ".docx")
                    || ($ext == ".zip")
                    || ($ext == ".PNG")
                    || ($ext == ".JPEG")
                    || ($ext == ".PJPEG")
                    || ($ext == ".JPG")
                    || ($ext == ".PDF")
                    || ($ext == ".DOC")
                    || ($ext == ".DOCX")
                    || ($ext == ".ZIP")
                    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 10000000)){

                      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {

                            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";

                       } else {


                        if (file_exists("../../uploads/logdocs/".$newFileName . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {

                            //nothing

                        } else {

                            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"../../uploads/logdocs/" .$newFileName . $newFileName2);

                            $fileLocation =  "/uploads/logdocs/" .$newFileName . $newFileName2;

                            if (empty($fileLocation)) {
                                $uploadComplete = 0;
                            } else {  
                                $uploadComplete = 1;
                            }
                         }
                      }
                    }
                } else {

                    $uploadComplete = 1;
                }

                if ($uploadComplete == 1) {

                    mysql_query("UPDATE system_modificationsLogs 
                        SET 
                        modificationLogUpload = '$fileLocation'
                        WHERE modificationsLogId = '$modificationsLogId'");
                }
```

Comment: i suggest you use an array for those large ifs and you can use if(in_array($ext, $arrayWithExtensions)) it will look better and you will have a lot of less lines of code for just this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are doing this in a loop.
On the first iteration, this line of code correctly "uploads", or more accurately moves the file which is in a tmp location.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"../../uploads/logdocs/" .$newFileName . $newFileName2);
```

On the second and later iteration(s) you are going to come back through, and try to move the same file, but the file is no longer there because you moved it in the first itteration.

You can use copy instead of move_uploaded_file.

```
copy($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../../uploads/logdocs/" .$newFileName . $newFileName2);
```

This will copy the file and leave the original tmp file in place to later be copied.

At the end of your script execution the tmp file will be destroyed.